# With Eclipse and Android, the IDE never shows the value of an exception

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator

On Eclipse with the Android SDK and IDE plugin, when I debug an application with a SecurityException, I only see the exception itself in the log, but the IDE never tells me the details of it. For example, LogCat might have:

```
01-10 17:03:35.959: ERROR/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
01-10 17:03:35.959: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
01-10 17:03:35.959: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
01-10 17:03:35.959: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
01-10 17:03:35.959: ERROR/System(58):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
```

But no where in this output do you see (1) what line in my code caused the SecurityException, or (2) the exception details -- specifically what permission is missing. I believe this should be on detailMessage.

In the IDE's debugger, a thread is suspended with RuntimeException, and the variables include another NullPointerException, which is seemingly unrelated to the logged SecurityException.

How do I get Eclipse/Android SDK to stop on the code that's actually causing a SecurityException to be thrown, and how do I access the details for that exception? Am I missing something painfully obvious in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding a Java Exception Breakpoint?

In the Debug perspective, bring the "Breakpoints" view to the top, click the "J!" icon and type "SecurityException". That should open the debugger at the exact point that exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to DDMS View and you can see LogCat.

Did you try using try/catch block to handle exception yourself?

Comment: The output I just posted was from LogCat.

Comment: I'd add a try/catch block if I knew what line of code was causing the exception to throw.